# Disable backordering for a specific user role in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

In woocommerce,I put my products on backordering with the backorder checkbox.
Now that everything is on backordering, I want to disable backordering for normal customers (and let it be for other user roles such as wholesale_customer).

I have the following code but when I add it as a plugin, I am unable to add something to my cart (I can push the add to cart button, but the cart stays empty):

```
/*Single product page: out of stock when product stock quantitiy is lower or equal to zero AND customer is not wholesale_customer.*/

add_filter('woocommerce_product_is_in_stock', 'woocommerce_product_is_in_stock' );

function woocommerce_product_is_in_stock( $is_in_stock ) {
    global $product;

    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $haystack= (array) $user->roles;
    $target=array('wholesale_customer');

    if($product->get_stock_quantity() <= 0 && count(array_intersect($haystack, $target)) == 0){

        $is_in_stock = false;
    }

    return $is_in_stock;
}

/*Single product page: max add to cart is the product's stock quantity when customer is not wholesale_customer.*/

function woocommerce_quantity_input_max_callback( $max, $product ) {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $haystack= (array) $user->roles;
    $target=array('wholesale_customer');

    if(count(array_intersect($haystack, $target)) == 0){

        $max= $product->get_stock_quantity();
    }

    return $max;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_max', 'woocommerce_quantity_input_max_callback',10,2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `woocommerce_is_purchasable( $is_purchasable, $product )` filter instead. It should return true or false.

Also, you also don't need to go to such lengths to get the user's role. A simple `if ( current_user_can( 'wholesale_customer' ) )` will suffice.

So, something like:

```
function my_is_purchasable( $is_purchasable, $product ) {
    if ( current_user_can( 'wholesale_customer' ) ) { 
        return true;
    } elseif ( $product->get_stock_quantity() <= 0 ) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return $is_purchasable;
    }
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'my_is_purchasable', 10, 2 );
```

*Note: This is just by way of demonstration, as I can't test it properly for you as I'm not at my desk right now.*

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code use dedicated `woocommerce_product_backorders_allowed` filter hook:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_backorders_allowed', 'products_backorders_allowed', 10, 3 );
function products_backorders_allowed( $backorder_allowed, $product_id, $product ){
    $user       = wp_get_current_user();
    $user_roles = (array) $user->roles;
    if( in_array( 'customer', $user_roles ) && ! in_array( 'wholesale_customer', $user_roles ) ){
        $backorder_allowed = false;
    }
    return $backorder_allowed;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should works.